# Как наложить цвет на PNG картинку, так чтобы цвет обтекал картинку?

Tags: css

Как же всё таки наложить цвет на PNG картинку, так чтобы цвет обтекал картинку?

**Сейчас разберемся!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все что вам нужно это создать блок с нужным вам цветом наложения через **background** и поверх него накинуть ***mask-image: url(<image.png>);***

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

.icon {
  --image: url(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/android/android-original.svg);
  
  /* Цвет наложения */
  background: red;
  
  /* Вставляем картинку */
  mask-image: var(--image);
  -webkit-mask-image: var(--image);
  
  /* Центрируем */
  mask-position: center center;
  -webkit-mask-position: center center;
  
  /* Убираем повторения */
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-size: contain;
  
  /* Расстягиваем */
  -webkit-mask-size: contain;
  
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon"></div>
```